# R code to convert the date-time format

Tags: r, date, datetime, dataframe

Hi I have the below dataframe, in which few dates have "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm" format and few "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm". However i want to change all to "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm" format

> Below, "02-05-2018 07:45" is in "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm" format. Which
>   means, 2nd of May. I need it to be converted to 5th of Feb i.e
>   "02/05/2018 07:45" which is in mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm" format

Input :

```
 Date / Time        Object Value
 02-05-2018 07:45   30
 02-05-2018 08:00   0
 1/30/2018 22:30    65.125
 1/30/2018 22:45    0
 1/30/2018 23:00    58
```

Output :

```
 Date / Time        Object Value
 02/05/2018 07:45   30
 02/05/2018 08:00   0
 1/30/2018 22:30    65.125
 1/30/2018 22:45    0
 1/30/2018 23:00    58
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Date / Time is a character you can get desired datetime in POSIXct format:

```
library(lubridate)
mdy_hm("02-05-2018 07:45")
```

or in character format:

```
library(lubridate)
as.character(mdy_hm("02-05-2018 07:45"))
```

Comment: No, Date-time variable is a character

Answer (score 0):

We can use `anytime` to convert multiple formats to 'DateTime' object

```
anytime::anytime(df1[,1])
#[1] "2018-02-05 07:45:00 IST" "2018-02-05 08:00:00 IST" "2018-01-30 22:30:00 IST" 
#[4] "2018-01-30 22:45:00 IST" "2018-01-30 23:00:00 IST"
```

It is better to keep in the date time class instead of changing to a different format.  But, it can changed with `format`

```
format(anytime::anytime(df1[,1]), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
#[1] "02/05/2018 07:45" "02/05/2018 08:00" "01/30/2018 22:30" 
#[4] "01/30/2018 22:45" "01/30/2018 23:00"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(DateTime = c("02-05-2018 07:45", "02-05-2018 08:00", 
"1/30/2018 22:30", "1/30/2018 22:45", "1/30/2018 23:00"), ObjectValue = c(30, 
0, 65.125, 0, 58)), .Names = c("DateTime", "ObjectValue"),
   class =  "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: its convereted to "yyyy-dd-mm" format

Comment: @Anagha  If you check the second option with `format`, it is converted to the expected format you showed

Comment: its throwing NAs for "02-05-2018 08:00" format

Comment: @Anagha Use the data in my post.  I have copied it from your post and it is not throwing NAs

Comment: @Anagha I can't reproduce the problem `anytime("02-05-2018 08:00")#
[1] "2018-02-05 08:00:00 IST"`